# How to iterate through files using pathlib.glob() when files names have digits of different length

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

`My Directory` looks like this:

```
P1_SAMPLE.csv
P2_SAMPLE.csv
P3_SAMPLE.csv
P11_SAMPLE.csv
P12_SAMPLE.csv
P13_SAMPLE.csv
```

My code looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\My Directory'

for fle in Path(file_path).glob('P*_SAMPLE.csv'):
    number = fle.name[1]
    print(number)
```

This gives output:

```
1
2
3
1
1
1
```

How do I make the code output the actual full digits for each file, like this:

```
1
2
3
11
12
13
```

Would prefer to use `fle.name[]` if possible. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

for fle in Path(file_path).glob('P*_SAMPLE.csv'):
    m = re.search(r'P(\d+)_SAMPLE.csv', fle.name)
    print(m.group(1))
```

You can even simplify this to:

```
m = re.search(r'(\d+)', fle.name)
```

Since a number only appears in one place within the filename.